# Javascript Carousel that shows/hides corresponding divs. jQuery function for hide all except selected

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a carousel with image thumbnails. When clicked they show the corresponding div and hide all the others. [Live Site Here.](http://test.tomsalta.com/?page_id=6)

The current script works, except for I have around 30 divs and corresponding thumbnails now instead of 3, and the client can add more through WordPress. So I need a more simple way to say "Hide all divs except for the one selected" without using actual div numbers.

HTML:

```
 <div class="carousel">
<a id="lnk1"><img src="images/projects/game1.jpg" /></a>
<a id="lnk2"><img src="images/projects/game2.jpg" /></a>
<a id="lnk3"><img src="images/projects/game3.jpg" /></a>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```

Current Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h1 = $("#div1").height();
    var h2 = $("#div2").height();
    var h3 = $("#div3").height();
$("#div1,#div2,#div3").height(Math.max(h1, h2, h3));
$("#div2,#div3").hide();

$("#lnk1").live('click', function() {
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2,#div3").hide();
});

$("#lnk2").live('click', function() {
    $("#div2").show();
    $("#div1,#div3").hide();
});

$("#lnk3").live('click', function() {
    $("#div3").show();
    $("#div1,#div2").hide();
});
```

Comment: can you tell us which library are you using? jcarousel?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you use the click event of the children(`anchor`) of the div 'carousel' for this. On click, first you hide all the elements (`div`) inside your 'content' `div`. Then use the '`this`' object to get the index of the cliked anchor. After that use that index to display the curresponding div. Here you can see the index is the one thing connecting the both. So you have to keep the same order in both.

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel" >
<a id="lnk1" >image 1</a>
<a id="lnk2" >image 2</a>
<a id="lnk3" >image 3</a>
<a id="other1" >image 4</a>   
<a id="other2" >image 5</a>  
</div>
<div class="content">
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
<div id="other_div1">div4</div>
<div id="other_div2">div5</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".carousel > a").live('click', function() {
    $(".content > div").hide(); //hide all divs
    $(".content > div").eq($(this).index()).show();//display curresponding div of the clicked anchor
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/3nMgA/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.siblings()`:

```
$('.carousel a').click(function() {
    $('.content div').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it works except for no matter which image I click it only shows div1 and hides all the others. It doesn't load the same numbered div. I know it's close but I am no jQuery expert.